# When is a point process a Poisson point process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, point-processes

I've seen several equivalent definitions of Poisson point processes in the literature, one of which is: a random set $X \subset V$ satisfying:

1. Independence of counts of $X$ in disjoint subsets of $V$
2. Counts are Poisson-distributed

(See e.g. 2.3.1, [Stochastic geometry and its applications](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Stochastic_Geometry_and_Its_Applications.html?id=4ikDDQAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y).)

(2) is usually assumed, but are there alternate conditions in which the Poisson-distributed count emerges? (As [this blog post](https://almostsuremath.com/2021/01/11/criteria-for-poisson-point-processes/) seems to suggest, though the Poisson counts are perhaps assumed at some point.)

I.e., is there a sense in which the Poisson process is *the* canonical process with the independence property (1)? If so, any sources would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that Section 2.4 of Volmue I of "An Introduction to the Theory of Point Processes" by Daley and Vere-Joney has the answers you want. The Poisson distribution of the counts can arise as a consequence of the independance property and doesn't need to be assumed in the right setting.